# Should I use DefaultEventExecutorGroup or custom Java Executor?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

I don't want to block UI (golden rule :). Should I:

A) create `DefaultEventExecutorGroup` and use it when I add my `ChannelHandler` to the pipeline:

```
pipeline.addLast(eventExecutorGroup, "foo", fooChannelHandler);
```

B) or use my custom java thread pool *inside* my `ChannelHandler` instance and then fire a task in my `messageReceived` method?

Using Netty 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DefaultEventExecutorGroup will take care that the tasks for each Channel be executed in the right order, which may be important or not depending on the protocol.

Comment: True. But if I have `HttpObjectAggregator` in front of my handler, then usage of `DefaultEventExecutorGroup` for not blocking the IO make no sense?

Comment: That's completely unrelated... You would put the EventExecutorGroup with the ChannelHandler that blocks in the ChannelPipeline

Comment: Yes, sorry, I realized later that my question was not related

Comment: I did some benchmarks on this and found that DefaultEventExecutor is giving less TPS. The scenario is an HTTP proxy. There's a source handler on one end and target handler on the other. I tried using a shared DefaultEventExecutor and also source and target handler's very own. When comparing this with using simple Java executor in the handlers themselves, with higher concurrency I saw DefaultEventExecutor giving less TPS. What could be the reason for this?